# Dapper issue with tiny int

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, dapper, tinyint

I am trying to migrate a database from MySQL to SQLServer using Dapper.

Almost everything is ok except with TinyInt fields.

Whatever the type I specify in my C# code, Dapper systematically throws an exception:

> {"Error parsing column 18 (COLUMN_WITH_PROBLEM=0 - SByte)"}.

It seems to be related with the fact that the value of one of the record in the MySQL database is null

I've tried:

- `int`, `int?`
- `byte`, `byte?`
- `Byte`, `Byte?`
- `sbyte`, `sbyte?`
- `SByte`, `SByte?`
- `short`, `short?`
- and even `boolean?`

Yet I always have the same issue.

What type do I have to specify in my C# code to avoid this error?

Obviously I can't change the column type in the Database.

Comment: Which ones have you tried?

Comment: @juharr it is in my question : int, int?, byte, byte?, Byte Byte?, sbyte, sbyte?, SByte, SByte? and even boolean?

Comment: Is the Tinyint column signed or unsigned?

Comment: A Tinyint in sql server should map to Byte in .Net... I understand you already tried it with no luck. can you post some relevant code as well?

Comment: @Bridge in mySQL tinyint is signed but in my case the only values I have are 0 and null

Comment: I am using Dapper so my code is simply     await idbOrigine.QueryAsync<T>(requeteSelect)   and Dapper is supposed to map the result of my requete to the type T , and in the T class, i've tried a lot of type for the field wich is mapped to the tinyint

Comment: [Possibly related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410866/dapper-is-throwing-an-invalid-cast-exception-when-trying-to-set-a-boolean-value)

Comment: @Bridge this question is related but doesn't help, I've tried to create a backing field and parse the value in int but I have always the same error

Answer (score 0):

Null-able byte? should work.

```
public class Foo
{
    public byte? Bar { get; set; }
}

    [Test]
    public void TestTinyint()
    {
        var result = _sqlConnection.Query<Foo>(@"select 0 as 'Bar' 
                                                union all select null as 'Bar'");
        Assert.That(result.First().Bar, Is.EqualTo(0));
        Assert.That(result.Last().Bar, Is.Null);
    }
```

It could be related to MySQL connector issue discussed [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/issues/552).

Comment: effectively your code works, i don't understand why mine doesn't.  there is a lot of columns but it may not affect Dapper. I'm even more lost

Comment: maybe because in your case 0 and null are not formatted as tinyint

Comment: I update the answer to a possible MySQL connector issue.